# Tring to call A simple Zoho API that returns a photo, and hit a wall of confusion?

Tags: asp.net-core, crm, zoho

I can't believe this seems so complicated or I am simply not understanding what's going on.

Basically I want to call the below API to retrieve the Avatar/Photo assigned to an Account in Zoho.

https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v6/download-image.html

I want to do this this from a server (.NET Core WebApi) application, from a webhook, upon receiving notification a new Account has been approved I would like to download the image to compliment the rest of the stored details.

With all the other API's I'm working with I register an application and get the client Id and secret, and configure them in the server and make the call.

However with Zoho, this get's confusing quickly as if I register a Self Client the token granted expires after 10 minutes! SO what do I do now?

I followed there instructions here to try to understand:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v3/api-collection.html
However when I actually try to make any calls they seem to fail.
[image]

In summary the question I guess is, what do I need to do to call a single Zoho Crm api reliably from another server based application, given the limit of 10 minute tokens!

I wanted to call one API and now I want to cry...

[image]

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing the code you tried?

Comment: because I don't know what code to write, hence the question.

Comment: To be more specific, in there doco' they suggest using an SDK, in which case the C# SDK however this version is not .NET Core compliant, I get some warning. So I would like to use the HTTP Client and just call the API. However there is no documentation that tells you how to do this, without going to a portal and getting a token, that expires after 10 minutes, in effect making it impossible to use in an application, as it will almost certainly expire from it runs in production.  I am talking about Server to Server call, not via  a user account.

Comment: ok, so it looks like I can configure the payment gateway with a refresh token, as that  doesn't expire... so I can manually generate that, configure it, then use it to get the other tokens..

Comment: no the above is not correct. It looks like I need to implement a full AUTH process flow of constant renewals on these tokens., Basically it looking like a lot of work just to get the AUTH flow implemented, with storing tokens and renewing them. Not even stripe, a payment gateway, does this madness for an api call.